# How can I delete a windows service by just knowing display name of the service in a batch script?

Tags: windows-services, batch-file

- First of all, I am not good at scripting and I need to delete a
  windows service in a batch file.
- The service name is randomly generated, I only know the display name
  of the script. What can I do?

I tried basically as a trial

```
@echo off
set sname = sc getkeyname "Display Name"
sc delete %sname%
```

Not Working..

Comment: Dare I even ask why the service name is randomly generated?

Comment: I am not sure of that, the service is created while installation which was not my job.It is a RabbitMQ service. I am scripting an uninstaller to clean all the services created. So basically service name is RabbitMQddw32fedsdas23 like that. I am also thinking for options whether I can use wildcards like RabbitMQ* or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a general format, you must fix some details:

```
@echo off
for /F %%s in ('sc getkeyname "Display Name"') do set sname=%%s
sc delete %sname%
```

For example, if the service name is not displayed in the first line:

```
for /F "skip=#" %%s in ('sc getkeyname "Display Name"') do set sname=%%s
```

If the service name does not appear at beginning of the line:

```
for /F "tokens=2" %%s in ('sc getkeyname "Display Name"') do set sname=%%s
```

We may help you whit more detail if you show us the info displayed by `sc getkeyname ...` and what the info you want is. I hope it helps.